# SQLite Update Stops ProgressBar

Tags: performance, android-sqlite, android-intentservice

In my startup activity I am kicking off a database sync in an IntentService and running a circular ProgressBar until a broadcast is received from the IntentService indicating that the task is complete.  While the database sync works, it stops the ProgressBar from spinning.  I confirmed this by commenting out the SQLite update task in which case the progressbar runs smoothly.

In my IntentService

```
 public class DatabaseSyncService extends IntentService {

    ... setup for database operation

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

      for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject update_row = response.getJSONObject(i);

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

                ... populate cv

        // insert new values into database
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(update_row.getInt("locationID"))};
        readingDb.update("ZLOCATION", cv, "ZREMOTE_ID=?", whereArgs);

     }
```

What can I do to prevent the SQLite "update" from stopping the circular progress bar?  Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: You need to run this as a background task

Comment: Isn't the IntentService a background task?  That's where the database update is being run from.